# Azure ARM templates parameters from PowerShell and File

Tags: azure, powershell, templates, azure-resource-manager

I was trying to figure out if its possible to deploy an ARM template to Azure using PowerShell but passing parameters both inline and from a parameter file.

For example if I had a parameter for a virtual machine name, that I wanted to pass inline during the New-AZResourceGroupDeployment command, but then have the rest of the parameters for the template to use from a parameter.json file?

So the command would be something like

New-AZResourceGroupDeployment -templateFile xxxxx -vmname (inline param) -templaterParameterFile ****

I seem to be able to get either or to work, but not together, so I wasn't sure if this was possible.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working.

the command does work, but it has to be using local parameter files, it won't work if you reference a URI for the param file.